# derivative of $[n \times \nabla \eta]^2$ with respect to $\eta$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I trying to implement an equation numerically, Numerically I can do it in, but was wondering if there is an analytical solution to it.

Here is the equation: 
$ f = [n \times \nabla \eta]^2$

Where, $n$ is a vector and $\eta$ is a scalar.

I need to implement $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mattos $\eta$ is a function but i will be defining it manually in my implementation